# Looping through a "function" object in javascript

Tags: javascript, object, loops

i have this project where i would like to merge a "function" object (in contrast to the JSON object - an object literal) with an existing object. i would want to get the "publicly visible" properties. however, when i do a *for in* loop, they don't show up. they don't trigger the `console.log()` inside. how do i get them?

```
//obj passed to extend() by external caller
//this is what obj it looked like when i console.log()'ed it
obj = function() {

    //skip these private ones
    var imPrivate = 'i should not be included';
    function imGetter() {}

    //i want these guys below:
    this.getter = imGetter;
    this.imPublic = "i should be included";

}

function extend(obj){
    console.log('i can see here');

    for (var key in obj) {
        console.log('you cannot see here');
    }​

    //...more of our code here
}
```

Comment: You would either need to run that function or create an instance of it with the `new` operator before any of those properties were set.

Comment: actually, the `obj` here is just to display what i was passed to the loop (as shown in the console). the loop is part of a function we named `extend`, which is irrelevant to the question :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those properties don't exist until you call the function.

Once you `var foo = new obj();` then you will see [the properties](http://jsfiddle.net/F77vz/) (on `foo`).

Alternatively, move the code that sets the properties so it is [outside the function](http://jsfiddle.net/F77vz/1/).

Comment: perfect. now i know how an uncalled object looks like in the console! (and call it when needed to be called).

Answer (score 0):

you could make it self execute:

```
var obj={};
(function(ns) { //skip these private ones   
    var imPrivate = 'i should not be included';

    function imGetter() {};
    //i want these guys below:  
    ns.getter = imGetter;
    ns.imPublic = "i should be included";
})(obj)
console.log('i can see here');
for (var key in obj) {
    console.log('you cannot see here '+key+" holds:"+obj[key]);
}
```